# how to build nested where on zend db

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Hello everyone  i want to build this query on zend db (zf1.9)

```
SELECT `p`.*, `r`.`name` AS `retailer`, `placer`.`name` AS `placer_name`, `placer`.`contact_firstname` AS `placer_firstname`, `placer`.`contact_lastname` AS `placer_lastname`, `placer`.`role_id` AS `placer_role_id`, `editor`.`name` AS `editor_name`, `editor`.`contact_firstname` AS `editor_firstname`, `editor`.`contact_lastname` AS `editor_lastname`, `editor`.`role_id` AS `editor_role_id` FROM `pos` AS `p`
     LEFT JOIN `retailers` AS `r` ON r.id = p.retailer_id
     LEFT JOIN `members` AS `placer` ON placer.id = p.placer_id
     LEFT JOIN `members` AS `editor` ON editor.id = p.editor_id WHERE (p.designer_id=116) AND ((placer.name  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_firstname  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_lastname  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (r.name  LIKE   '%demo%')) AND (`r`.`name` LIKE  '%M%') ORDER BY `p`.`id` asc
```

how can i do that?my problem is only

```
WHERE (p.designer_id=116) AND ((placer.name  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_firstname  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_lastname  LIKE   '%demo%') OR (r.name  LIKE   '%demo%')) AND (`r`.`name` LIKE  '%M%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply split your nested `where`-clause into multiple `and`-statements (with nested `or`):

first:

```
(p.designer_id=116)
```

second:

```
((placer.name LIKE '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_firstname LIKE '%demo%') OR (placer.contact_lastname LIKE '%demo%') OR (r.name  LIKE '%demo%'))
```

third:

```
(`r`.`name` LIKE '%M%')
```

---

In ZEND every `AND` is an seperate `where`-clause and might look like something like this (untested! only for better understanding!):

```
->where("p.designer_id=116");
->where("(placer.name  LIKE ?) 
        OR (placer.contact_firstname LIKE ?) 
        OR (placer.contact_lastname LIKE ?) 
        OR (r.name LIKE ?)", '%demo%', '%demo%', '%demo%', '%demo%');
->where("r.name LIKE ?", '%M%');
```

(Note: I've added manual linebreaks for better readability)

Comment: here how to use between in where for find seleted date from to to data

Answer (score 1):

I think following is better. NEST will open the bracket  UNNEST will close bracket

```
$where = new Sql\Where();
$where->NEST//start braket
->equalTo('col','someVal')
->OR
->equalTo('col','secondVal')
->UNNEST; //close bracet
```

This will produce WHRE (col=someVal OR col=secondVal)
Also remember after termination (putting ;) if NEST is already there it will add NUNEST automatically 
eg
I think following is better. NEST will open the bracket UNNEST will close bracket

```
$where = new Sql\Where();
$where->NEST//start braket
->equalTo('col','someVal')
->OR
->equalTo('col','secondVal');
$where->OR;
$where->NEST//start braket
->equalTo('col','someVal1')
->OR
->equalTo('col','secondVal2');
```

This will produce WHRE (col=someVal OR col=secondVal) OR (col=someVal2 OR col=secondVal2)